# Apply complex transformation to an image using matplotlib and numpy

Tags: python, image-processing, matplotlib, plot

Hi I am trying to apply the mobius transformation to an image using matplotlib. This is python code to do this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from numpy import *


img = mpimg.imread('test.jpg') # load an image
zi = [766j, 512+766j, 256+192j]
wi = [738j, 512+496j, 256+173j]
r = ones((600,700,3),dtype=uint8)*255 # empty-white image
for i in range(img.shape[1]):
    for j in range(img.shape[0]):
        z = complex(i,j)
        qf = ((wi[0] * (-wi[1] * (zi[0]-zi[1]) * (z-zi[2]) + wi[2] * (z-zi[1]) * (zi[0]-zi[2])) - wi[1]*wi[2]*(z-zi[0]) * (zi[1]-zi[2])))
        qs = (wi[2]*(zi[0]-zi[1])*(z-zi[2])-wi[1]*(z-zi[1])*(zi[0]-zi[2])+wi[0]*(z-zi[0])*(zi[1]-zi[2]))
        w = qf/qs
        r[int(imag(w)),int(real(w)),:] = img[j,i,:]

plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(img,origin='lower',aspect='auto')
plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(r,origin='lower',aspect='auto')
plt.show()
```

if I run this code, I get the following result.
[image: plot]

If you see the right side, the size is changed. I want to know the way to fit the result image in the box. The way I did is I hard code the result image size and run the code. However, since the mobius transformation expands and shrink the image, sometimes I get very small image and sometimes I get very big image. Anyone can solve this problem??Thanks!

Comment: @SaulloCastro Can you show me an example?? I tried it but it seems not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to find the x limits and y limits of your transformed image:

```
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
i, j = np.where(np.all(r!=255, axis=2))
xlimits = j.min(), j.max()
ylimits = i.min(), i.max()
plt.xlim(xlimits)
plt.ylim(ylimits)
```

the `set_aspect()` was added to show the image in its original aspect ratio. `numpy.where()` will find the row and column indices where the image is not white (255, 255, 255), it is taking the minimum and maximum indices to set the new limits.

Comment: @eChung00 I liked your code very much, you should try to get rid of these for loops using more of `numpy` vectorized operations...

Comment: Thanks for your advise... I feel that it gets slower if the size of image gets bigger..So I will try.. ^^